Advanced math courses for theoretical physics students
Theoretical physics studies concerning statistical mechanics, dynamical systems and analytical classical mechanics all require working knowledge of mathematical concepts and theories (e.g. manifolds, functional and topological spaces, measure, etc) well beyond what is typically taught, the first couple of years, in the basic real/complex analysis and geometry courses.
So what generally happens is that advanced math concepts are introduced "as-needed" and very mildly "explained" within the theoretical physics courses.
In my opinion this is not at all suited to make students really understand the physical theories they are supposed to learn.
Advanced math courses in functional analysis, differential geometry and topology should really be an integral part of a typical theoretical physics study path, which is not the case, at least in Italian universities (as long as I know about).
Any opinion on this from students and professors in Italy is welcome, as well as from people with experience abroad.

This is a Q&A forum, I see no question related to physics here.

This belongs to a different forum for physics or math education, since its not about physics.

I think the question is more suitable for the Academia community

Thank you all. I will move it to the academia community.

Crossposted to https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/212955/57873

To really understand physics theories requires, first and foremost, an understanding of physics and the experimental results behind them, not the mathematics.  I would hope no physics BSc course places mathematics before experiment.


So what generally happens is that advanced math concepts are introduced "as-needed" and very mildly "explained" within the theoretical physics courses.

This depends on the country and the specific university. E.g., the freshmen and sophomore years of my schooling were filled with courses like mathematical analysis, complex analysis, analytic geometry, (ordinary) differential equations, mathematical physics (i.e. partial differential equations), while physics was relegated to a generic multi-semester general physics - approximately corresponding to Feynmann's lectures or Berkley course of physics. The serious courses like theoretical mechanics, E&M, Quantum mechanics, Statistical physics were taught only in the junior year, followed by more applied ones, like semiconductor physics, laser physics, physics of waveguides, etc.
And I openly admit that I am not a high theoretical physicist in the HEP sense, but merely a theorist in the field of semiconductor nanostructures. Still, there was a great deal of math that I had to add during my masters and PhD (like functional analysis, group theory, and those dealing with stochastic processes), as well as by simply reading books (mostly QFT for condensed matter stuff in my case.)
